# Why i can not center div in CSS?

Tags: html, css, django

Hei!

I am trying to center divs on my website, but nothing moves/change. Everything stays on the left side, even now when I have changed all divs to center. I am checking in many browsers, but still everything is on the left side. What can be reason?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: you are missing all the quotes around id

Answer (score 0):

In your case, You can achieve this by using flexbox.

Just replaced from

```
#container
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

To

```
#container
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}
```